# Is it possible to thicken oat milk based sauce when dairy would naturally be thicker?

Tags: sauce, oat-milk

After switching to oat milk I recently tried to use it in a [box-dinner](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Betty-Crocker-Tuna-Helper-Tetrazzini-Spaghetti-Creamy-Sauce-Mix-7-3-oz/14053149) that I previously used dairy milk in. I noticed that it didn't thicken into a sauce nearly as well.

This kind of makes sense intuitively; oat milk doesn't curdle the same way, it lasts longer, it's just not going to respond in the way dairy milk would. That said, is there something I can do to help it along like adding flour or cornstarch? I'd rather just have one type of milk for drinking and cooking if possible.

Comment: How many times did this happen? It would be rare for a box dinner to use a thickening mechanism that requires dairy milk. If it only happened once, it's worth trying again, because there is a high chance it was a fluke.

Answer (score 3):

Both flour and starch will gelatinize (=thicken) any random liquid. Milk is not directly related to this reaction, it works even with juice or plain water.

As flour can leave an undesired aftertaste if not cooked through properly, I would recommend corn or potato starch instead.

The standard dose for sauces is 1-2 teaspoons per cup of liquid, but as your dish already contains corn starch as thicker, I’d suggest simply making a slurry of a spoonful of starch and some cold water or your plant milk and add it slowly to the hot sauce until you reach the desired consistency.